# Is there a nice way to write pseudocode?

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to sketch out some pseudocode and then share it with other people that won't be using emacs.

Is there a nice way to do this? I'm trying to do it in org-mode, but it's not indenting properly, etc...

Comment: Someone has written a [pseudocode-mode](https://github.com/jsalzbergedu/pseudocode-mode), but as of this writing it only offers syntax highlighting, no indentation.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a pseudo-code mode, less so support for that in org-mode.

You can, however, write pseudo-code in `#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE` blocks, surely without indentation, or you decide for a true language as base syntax and pseudo-code in that and get indentation and pretty syntax highlighting. Ruby might be a good candidate, or good old C/C++, maybe Java...

This is how it could look like:

```
#+HEADER: :exports both :results output
#+BEGIN_SRC ruby
class Pseudoclass
  def pseudofunction(items)
    add five to each item
  end
end

pseudoinstance = new Pseudoclass instance
call pseudofunction of pseudoinstance with list 2, 3, 4
#+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you accept to share your pseudocode in LaTeX or PDF format, you could use the package `minted` to mix teletype & well-indented expression with LaTeX math expression. Here is an example of the well-known Prim's algorithm:

```
#+begin_export latex
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||,mathescape=true]{text}
Prim's Algorithm(|$V, s$|)
|$T = \varnothing$|
|$U = \{ s \}$|
while (|$U \neq V$|)
    let |$(u, v)$| be the lowest cost edge in the cut |$(U, V-U)$|
    |$T = T \cup \{(u, v)\}$|
    |$U = U \cup \{v\}$|
\end{minted}
#+end_export
```

which it's rendered as 
[image]

If you want only share this pseudocode snippet, you just have to select this block and call `org-latex-export-as-latex` or `org-latex-export-to-pdf` depending on what format you want to export (you might want to slightly modify the org-mode options to have a satisfying layout). To write easily pseudocode, you can, of course, change the `minted` math expression separator, and use `yasnippet` or latex custom block to get rid of those bunch of options.